# java expression finds multiple words

Tags: java, regex

I'm a Java newbie, I have a text file which contains information like below:

```
    1.Store 123 has cloth style B.
    2.Store 253 has cloth style D.
    3.Store 27 has cloth style A.
    4.Store 164 has cloth style F.
    ......
```

then I'm trying to put useful information(just store number and style number) into a set and print out, set should be like:

```
[123 B, 253 D, 27 A, 164 F, ...]
```

I tried this:

```
    Set<String> setStoreStyle = new HashSet<String>(); 
    Pattern patternStoreStyle = Pattern.compile("Store (.+?) has cloth style(.+?).");

    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(MyTextfilePath);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));

    for (String line = br.readLine(); line != null; line = br.readLine()){

        Matcher matcherStoreStyle = patternStoreStyle.matcher(line);

        if(matcherStoreStyle.find()){
            String a = matcherStoreStyle.group(1);
            setStoreStyle.add(a);
        }
     }  
     br.close();
     System.out.println(setStoreStyle);
```

But I just get

```
[123, 253, 27, 164, ...]
```

Any ideas to fix it?

Comment: Escape the last dot (`\\.`) and combine the 2 captured values.

Comment: Accessing `matcherStoreStyle.group(2)` might help...

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You access the first capture group, but not the second:

```
String a = matcherStoreStyle.group(1) + " " + matcherStoreStyle.group(2);
```

Also, as @WictorStribizew notes, you should escape the last `.` in the pattern, so that it matches a literal period, rather than any character.

Comment: Awesome! I forget to add group(2), it works now! Thank you so much!

Comment: @DBFlying If this answered your question, please mark it as accepted (press the tick underneath the voting buttons)